# Why do these two ways of finding the sum of the sizes of groups larger than 1 disagree?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group the rows in a table by the first two columns, and sum the sizes of groups that have sizes larger than 1. I have thought of two ways to do it.

The first way:

```
SELECT SUM(size)
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as size
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY col1, col2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)  AS X
```

returns 307.

The second way:

```
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM mytable
```

which returns 36835, and

```
 SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CONCAT(col1, col2))
 FROM mytable
```

which returns 36637.

Subtract  36835 - 36637 = 198.

I was wondering why the two ways don't agree with each other?

To get the schema of the table, I run:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'mytable'
```

which outputs:

```
 COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_DEFAULT IS_NULLABLE  DATA_TYPE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
 col1 NULL YES nvarchar 255 
  col2 NULL YES nvarchar 255
```

Comment: Are `col1` and/or `col2` ***nullable***?

Comment: We'd really need your table definition to answer this.

Comment: @pm yes. How shall I modify the two ways?

Comment: @Tim We mean, edit your question to post the table definition for `mytable`.  Your question can't be reliably answered as is.

Comment: Try `SELECT * WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL` and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: @PM77-1 it's 17. It's actually  three columns and the omitted column ha the same properties as the first two

Answer (score 1):

The operation DISTINCT(CONCAT(col1, col2)) will treat all records with either col1 or col2 equal null as the same.  There can be many non-null col2 values when col1 is null.  And many non-null col1 values when col2 is null.  All these get counted as 1 set because CONCAT returns null for all of them. The GROUP BY does not count these as one set.

Concatenation is going to be error prone and can be a poor performer.  A subquery might be the best way for this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
    FROM mytable
    ) t
```

Comment: FYI Using a checksum in place of a concatenation of several columns is not reliable.